# search records between two timings in unix

Tags: unix

```
start_time=22:15:14 (second line)
end_time=01:05:15 ( last but one)
```

I want all those records between these timings.

```
Jan 3 22:14:14 Program: p1: PID=1681586: Thread 9 - Record type=1 (p1a): 0 processed OK, 0 failed
Jan 3 22:15:14 Program: p1: PID=1681586: Thread 9 - Record type=2 (p1b): 0 processed OK, 0 failed
Jan 3 22:16:14 Program: p1: PID=1681586: Thread 9 - Record type=3 (p1c): 2 processed OK, 4 failed
Jan 3 22:17:14 Program: p1: PID=1681586: Thread 9 - Record type=4 (p1d): 0 processed OK, 0 failed
Jan 3 22:17:14 Program: p1: PID=1664884: Thread 5 - Record type=1 (p1a): 0 processed OK, 0 failed
Jan 3 22:17:14 Program: p1: PID=1664884: Thread 5 - Record type=2 (p1b): 0 processed OK, 0 failed
Jan 3 22:17:14 Program: p1: PID=1664884: Thread 5 - Record type=3 (p1c): 3 processed OK, 5 failed
Jan 3 22:17:14 Program: p1: PID=1664884: Thread 5 - Record type=4 (p1d): 0 processed OK, 0 failed
Jan 3 22:17:15 Program: p1: PID=1663618: Thread 14 - Record type=1 (p1a): 0 processed OK, 0 failed
Jan 3 22:17:15 Program: p1: PID=1663618: Thread 14 - Record type=2 (p1b): 0 processed OK, 0 failed
Jan 4 01:17:15 Program: p1: PID=1663618: Thread 14 - Record type=2 (p1b): 0 processed OK, 0 failed
Jan 4 01:17:15 Program: p1: PID=1663618: Thread 14 - Record type=2 (p1b): 0 processed OK, 0 failed
Jan 4 01:17:15 Program: p1: PID=1663618: Thread 14 - Record type=2 (p1b): 0 processed OK, 0 failed
Jan 4 01:05:15 Program: p1: PID=1663618: Thread 14 - Record type=2 (p1b): 0 processed OK, 0 failed
Jan 4 01:17:15 Program: p1: PID=1663618: Thread 14 - Record type=2 (p1b): 0 processed OK, 0 failed
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you say 'between these times', do you mean that you must find all log records between those two times, even if those specific times do not appear in the log? For example, if the start time is 01:02:03 and the end time is 04:05:06, then you need to find records such as 02:03:04, even if neither end marker appears? Where does the date fit in? Could there be repeated sets of records in the time range on successive days?  Can you show some sample values for the start and end times, and some sample log records, some that should be selected and some that should not?

Comment: What is the format of your log records?

Comment: refer sample log as shown above - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/start_time=hh:mm:ss/,/end_time=hh:mm:ss/' your_log_file
```

Comment: With the information currently available, that's probably about as good as you can do, but it is unlikely to be the final answer.  See my comments to the main question for some of the issues that are not covered in the question.

Comment: Hi, I getting this error - Can you please assist further sed '/22:10:00/,/23:04:17/' time_file2
sed: /22:10:00/,/23:04:17/ is not a recognized function.

Comment: Try `sed '/22:10:00/,/23:04:17/p' time_file2`